# Redirecting to a parent folder because child folder is not available (on a Joomla website)

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I want to use `.htaccess` file to redirect requests to a parent folder because part of the requested path (URL) is no longer available. I managed to do it for a simple HTML-based website. However, I want to implement this on a website built using `Joomla 4`. All of my trials failed on the Joomla implementation.

**I think I need a solution that would "redirect" the user to *a new page.* In other words, when the user enters `<something>/parent/child/<something_else>` in the address bar, the browser should redirect the request to `<something>/parent/<something_else>` in the address bar.**

The Joomla-based website has a 2-level categorisation of elements. I want to unpublish the 2nd level.

Current path: https://example.com/parent/child/abc.html

I want to re-write URLs having `child` (as demonstrated above) by removing `child` from them (see below.)

Required path: https://example.com/parent/abc.html

If the website is a simple HTML-based website, using the solution below, the browser shows the URL the user entered in the address bar but fetches the HTML page that the `RewriteRule` redirects to. This is not bad, but my website is NOT a static HTML-based one!

However, if the structure is a Joomla-based website, using the solution below, the browser shows the URL the user entered in the address bar and FAILS to fetch the HTML page that the `RewriteRule` redirects to. I think this happens because the URL the user entered in the address bar does NOT exist. **Is there a way to redirect to a new URL that is displayed on the browser's address bar?**

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/parent/child/.+$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)parent.*?([^/]+)$ $1parent/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by using Joomla's built-in `redirects`. The only issue with these redirects is that they only accept absolute paths, which makes it impossible to test them on a non-prod environment. To use them on Joomla 4/5:
Administrator > System > Manage > Redirects > New

Expired URL: `https://example.com/parent/child/abc.html`

New UR: `https://example.com/parent/abc.html`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've updated my answer because the first version did not work as desired.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/parent/child/(.*)$ $1/parent/$2 [L,R=302]
```

I recommend using `R=302` during testing. If everything works, use `R=301`.

`^`   start of string/line
`$`   end of string/line
`.*`  match any character (greedy) - match as much as possible
`()`  capture group - treat multiple characters as a single unit
`$1`  is replaced with the text that matches the 1st capture group
`$2`  is replaced with the text that matches the 2nd capture group

Examples:
`example.com/test/parent/child/index.html` is redirected to
`example.com/test/parent/index.html`

`example.com/test/parent/child/sub/` is redirected to
`example.com/test/parent/sub/`

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time. However, it did not work. Your code redirected (http://localhost/web/testing/parent/child/index.html) to (http://localhost/parent/index.html).  I think your understanding of the use of the ? is not correct. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Sorry. I've updated my answer and changed the htaccess code. Please take a look at the two examples and tell me if this is as you want it to be and if I have understood you correctly this time.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Unfortunately, the new code did not help. I want to change the URL that appears on the address bar from (localhost/web/testing/parent/child/index.html) to (localhost/web/testing/parent/index.html). Your code (and my original code) redirects to the desired page but does NOT change the URL in the address bar. Since the sub-folder (child) is deleted, the redirect code does NOT work (on Joomla). I think we need to change the URL displayed on the address bar.